# super() method initializes only some parameters

Tags: python, class, initialization

while programming a minigame, I stumbled across something I cant explain myself (fairly new to python).
This is my code:

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self, x, y, hitpoints=1, color=(255, 0, 0), width=75, height=35):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.hitpoints = hitpoints


class Ball(Block):
    def __init__(self, x, y, size, color=(255, 255, 255), velocity=1):
        super().__init__(self, x, y, color)
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.size = size
```

I initialize the object ball with

```
ball = Ball(x=200, y=200, size=30)
```

Problem arises when I call ball.x, as it returns 
`<Objects.Ball object at 0x00000249425A3508>`.

If i call ball.y it works as intended and returns 200.

I can fix the whole problem by modifying the class Ball as follows:

```
class Ball(Block):
    def __init__(self,x, y, size, color=(255, 255, 255), velocity=1):
        super().__init__(self, y, color)
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.size = size
        self.x = x
```

Can somebody explain to me why this happens?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `super` without `self` argument:

```
super().__init__(x, y, color=color)
```

[This PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/) explains how this works:

> The new syntax:
>
> `super()`
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> `super(__class__, <firstarg>)`
>
> where `__class__` is the class that the method was defined in, and
>    is the first parameter of the method (normally `self` for
>   instance methods, and `cls` for class methods).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!! I knew it was very simple.
Can you explain me the difference between super with the self argument and super without it?

Comment: @nhaus it is not really very simple :) I also added a link to PEP where you can learn more.